# Mapping an optional with Gson

Tags: java, java-8, gson, option-type

I currently have the following code:

```
String response = HttpClient.get(url);
Trip trip = new Gson().fromJson(response, Trip.class);
```

I have transformed above code so that HttpClient.get() returns an optional of a String, being the responsebody.
I was wondering if I could make above code a one-liner so that I could have something like:

```
HttpClient.get(url).map(r -> new Gson().fromJson(r, Trip.Class))
```

Does this make sense?
How can I make above code function?

Comment: Looks ok, what is your question/problem? How does which code not function?

Comment: HttpClient.get(url).map(r -> new Gson().fromJson(r, Trip.Class)) does not work. The map function cannot perform the mapping and return me a JsonObject.

Comment: I do not understand what "does not work" means. Is there a compile error? An error message at runtime? Something else? Maybe adding a bit more of the code around that line would help.

Comment: can you show more code? - hard to guess what you want to achieve here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as you've mentioned, `HttpClient.get(url)` after refactoring now returns an `Optional<String>` instead of `String`, and then you want to perform a mapping function upon the `String` contained within the Optional into a `Trip` instance.

You're actually close, your issue is that you're not *unwrapping* the value contained within the `Optional<Trip>` returned after the mapping of `map(r -> new Gson().fromJson(r, Trip.Class))` if present. There are several methods to unwrap an `Optional<T>` depending on which you find the most appropriate for the task at hand.

a couple of examples below:

unwrapping using `orElse`:

```
Trip trip = HttpClient.get(url)
                      .map(r -> new Gson().fromJson(r, Trip.Class))
                      .orElse(null); // or provide a default value if you have it in place
```

using `ifPresent`:

```
HttpClient.get(url)
          .map(r -> new Gson().fromJson(r, Trip.Class))
          .ifPresent(e -> /* do something with the element*/);
```

For all the other methods used to unwrap an `Optional<T>` type can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: That was the final piece in the puzzle. Thank you very much for the clear answer.